# How to view all IE Trusted Sites when security settings are managed?

Tags: internet-explorer, security-policy, managed

If the Security Zones for Internet Explorer are managed by my system administrator, the list of Trusted Sites is disabled and I cannot scroll through the list. Is there a way I can view the full list of Trusted Sites?

[image: Trusted sites]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In the [registry](/questions/tagged/registry), perform a search for a URL that is known to be trusted. This should get you to the relevant key where you can see all of the others.

On my Windows 7 installation, the path appears to be **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey**, which is slightly different from [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/303786/47321).

The key should contain several string values with a name indicating the URL and numeric data indicating the zone, one of the following by default.

- 0 = My Computer
- 1 = Local Intranet Zone
- 2 = Trusted sites Zone
- 3 = Internet Zone
- 4 = Restricted Sites Zone

Comment: Mine are all under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Answer (score 29):

Depends upon your firm whether the list is under HKLM or HKCU.  Here's a quick Powershell command to get the list

```
$(get-item "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey").property

$(get-item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey").property
```

Comment: +1: This is the only solution which worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: Remove the ".property" on the end of each line to see which zone the site is configured for: 1 = Local Intranet, 2 = Trusted Sites, 3 = Restricted Sites

Answer (score 3):

From powershell:

```
Get-itemproperty "hkcu:\Software\policies\microsoft\windows\currentversion\internet settings\ZoneMapKey"
```

Comment: Can you explain this answer/flesh it out a bit more for those who don't know PS as well?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Start -> type **gpedit.msc** -> hit Enter
- navigate to Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel -> Security Page
- in the right-hand panel, double-click on the **Site to Zone Assignment List** option, then click **Show...**
- trusted sites are the ones with **2** in the Value column (1 = Intranet, 3 = Internet, 4 = Restricted)

If that doesn't work (that option is set to "Not Configured" or the list is empty), try the same, except instead of Computer Configuration, start with User Configuration.

Comment: Both of these settings are "Not Configured" and the lists are empty.

Comment: "You do not have permission to perform this action" - gpedit also locked down

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following solution, I hope others will find it useful as well.

I have limited rights, only local, not enough to open and view `GPEDIT` on AD level.

So, what I did, and works, is to open a command prompt (as Admin) and run the command:

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>GPResult /V /SCOPE Computer /H c:\temp\stuff.txt`

Then perform a search e.g. for the "ZoneMapKey"

`C:\WINDOWS\system32>find "ZoneMapKey" c:\temp\stuff.txt >> c:\temp\sites.txt`

Keep in mind there are other keys that might require your attention, like the "approvedactivexinstalsites"...

You will have an output like:

`KeyName:     Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey\https://www.wesayso.com`

Clean it up (I use Excel, use the \ as seperator and be done with it) and you will have a great list.

Comment: I tried this but got an error "ERROR: Invalid Syntax. Options /U, /P, /R, /V, /Z cannot be specified along with /X, /H."

Comment: C:\WINDOWS\system32>GPResult /V /SCOPE COMPUTER >> c:\temp\stuff.txt  generate the file for me.  "COMPUTER" in caps per the help file.  Use >> to write to file instead of /H

Answer (score 2):

This one works on my Windows 7 machine. It was set by my company's domain controller.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains" -Recurse > c:\result.txt
Get-ChildItem -Path "Registry::HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains" -Recurse
"DONE"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an enhanced version of the script that translates the zone type number in the registry to its name as seen in the IE explorer settings dialog box.

```
$_RegKeyList1 = @()
$_RegKeyList2 = @()
$_RegKeyList3 = @()
$_RegKeyInfo  = @()


$_RegKeyList1 = $(Get-item 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).property  


$_RegKeyList2 = $(Get-item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).property | Out-GridView


$_RegKeyList3 = $_RegKeyList1 + $_RegKeyList2 

Foreach($_RegValueName in $_RegKeyList3){

    $_RegValue = $(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey' -Name $_RegValueName  )

    Switch($_RegValue.$_RegValueName){

         0 {$_ZoneType = 'My Computer'}
         1 {$_ZoneType = 'Local Intranet Zone'}
         2 {$_ZoneType = 'Trusted sites Zone'}
         3 {$_ZoneType = 'Internet Zone'}
         4 {$_ZoneType = 'Restricted Sites Zonet'}

    }

    $_RegKeyInfo += "$_RegValueName,$_ZoneType"

}
```

Above we see how to gather the registry value names in a registry key and then get the data of each of those values. As each enter separates the value name and the value data with a comma, it could be further enhanced to output to a file with the csv extension and then opened in Excel. Many more possibilities if you want an actual report. But if just need to know what is the site list this will show most of them.

Answer (score 1):

on windows 10
The URL are saved in
***Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey***

to get the values you can brows to the above key or via PowerShell

```
Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey"
```

Answer (score 0):

My key was located here (in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, not HKEY_CURRENT_USER)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey
```

I could right-click "ZoneMapKey" and choose "Export"

This .reg file can be opened in Notepad to view (and search) the text contents.

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell script provides a list from both registry keys if they are populated and uses the out-gridview cmdlet to provide a search capability using the out-gridview filter field.

```
$_List1 = @()
$_List2 = @()
$_List3 = @()

$_List1 = $(Get-item 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).property  

$_List2 = $(Get-item 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).property | Out-GridView

$_List3 = $_List1 + $_List2 
$_List3 | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick this in Powershell for a list of the trusted sites:

```
Get-ItemProperty  "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMapKey" | fl
```

1 = Intranet zone – sites on your local network.
2 = Trusted Sites zone – sites that have been added to your trusted sites.
3 = Internet zone – sites that are on the Internet.
4 = Restricted Sites zone – sites that have been specifically added to your restricted sites.

Answer taken from:
https://blogs.sulross.edu/gfreidline/2017/06/20/show-ie-trusted-sites-from-powershell/